# What happens if there is no exit system call in an assembly program?

Tags: linux, assembly, operating-system, termination

In an assembly program, the `.text` section is loaded at `0x08048000`; the `.data` and the `.bss` section comes after that.

What would happen if I **don't** put an `exit` syscall in the `.text` section? Would it lead to the `.data` and the `.bss` section being interpreted as code causing "unpredictable" behavior? When will the program terminate -- probably after every "instruction" is executed?

I can easily write a program without the `exit` syscall, but testing if `.data` and `.bss` gets executed is something I don't know because I guess I would have to know the real machine code that is generated under-the-hoods to understand that.

I think this question is more about "How would OS and CPU handle such a scenario?" than assembly language, but it is still interesting to know for assembly programmers etc.

Comment: Execution would continue into whatever is after your code, yes. That will probably hit an invalid instruction sooner or later, or you will run into unmapped memory. If you are extremely lucky, you might hit a harmless endless loop in which case your program wouldn't terminate.

Comment: @Jester I'd say more chances of winning the lottery than hitting an endless loop.

Comment: @TonyTannous I did say "extremely lucky" :D However, you can make an endless loop in x86 using 2 bytes and assuming random memory contents that's already way better chance than any lottery I know. Unfortunately you are likely to hit some zero bytes instead of random, and that is `add al, [eax]` on x86 which will probably fault.

Comment: For the record, `00 00` decodes as `add  [eax], al`:  memory *destination*, not memory source, so EAX (or RAX in 64-bit code) has to be pointing at writeable memory, but repeated execution doesn't change the low byte of the address.

Comment: Related: [Nasm segmentation fault on RET in \_start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19760002) - `_start` isn't a function, there's nothing to return to. You need to make an exit system-call.  That Q&A has actual code examples for x86 / x86-64.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The processor does not know where your code ends.  It faithfully executes one instruction after another until execution is redirected elsewhere (e.g. by a jump, call, interrupt, system call, or similar).

If your code ends without jumping elsewhere, the processor continues executing whatever is in memory after your code.  It is fairly unpredictable what exactly happens, but eventually, your code typically crashes because it tries to execute an invalid instruction or tries to access memory that it is not allowed to access.

If neither happens and no jump occurs, eventually the processor tries to execute unmapped memory or memory that is marked as “not executable” as code, causing a segmentation violation.  On Linux, this raises a `SIGSEGV` or `SIGBUS`.  When unhandled, these terminate your process and optionally produce core dumps.

If you're curious, run under a debugger and look at disassembly of the faulting instruction.

Comment: At the CPU level, the exception you're talking about is a page-fault (`#PF`), not segment-related.  A 32-bit or 64-bit process on x86 Linux runs with CS base=0 / limit = unlimited.  The "segmentation" in `SIGSEGV` has basically nothing to do with x86 segments, because that's not what x86 Linux uses for memory protection.

Comment: @PeterCordes I would prefer if you removed all mention of CPU-specific details as otherwise readers will be confused if this applies to x86 only or also to other architectures.  I had intentionally written the answer without such references to avoid this uncertainty.

Comment: Maybe I should post a separate answer with x86 details?  This is a nice question for a canonical duplicate, but the answer doesn't show how to actually fix the problem for those who don't know.  That was the compromise I was trying to strike.  (I'd typed the `00 00` part before noticing that the question wasn't x86 specific; maybe I should have taken it out.  My comment from 4 years ago is also x86-specific, for better or for worse :/)  The `0x08048000` .text address in the question is what `ld` uses for 32-bit x86 Linux non-PIE, but it might also use the same address on others.

Comment: Most of the other Q&As with examples of how to `_exit` are about attempts to `ret` from `_start`, not falling off the end, so they don't work as well as a single duplicate for questions like [Assembly-segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28017926) where that appears to be the problem (although that one has some confusing text in the question which implies otherwise, but isn't a MCVE of it.)

Comment: This is of course your answer, so it's your call what it says.  Let me know if you decide to take out the x86 stuff; if I don't find a better canonical for x86 Q&As that fall off the end of `_start`, I might just add a separate answer here.  Maybe also with some mention of the equivalents for ARM and AArch64 Linux if that isn't too cluttered.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, please do.

Comment: Finally got around to posting those edits as a new answer to make this a better dup target, inspired by a couple recent duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this problem, see *[Nasm segmentation fault on RET in _start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760002/nasm-segmentation-fault-on-ret-in-start)* for correct ways to make an exit system-call in 32 or 64-bit x86 code for Linux or Windows.  (The entry point, `_start`, isn't a function in Linux; the stack pointer points at `argc`, not a return address, so `ret` doesn't work either.)  For other ISAs or OSes, check their manuals or look at existing examples for how to exit.

See also [What is the correct constant for the exit system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915010/what-is-the-correct-constant-for-the-exit-system-call) re: `#include <sys/syscall.h>` in a `.S` file to get constants like `SYS_exit`( or `SYS_exit_group`) on Unix-like OSes.

Or in assemblers that can't use C headers directly, look for `asm/unistd.h` on Linux; for x86-64 vs. -32, see `unistd_64.h` vs. `unistd_32.h`.  (And/or see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922099/polygot-include-file-for-nasm-yasm-and-c) for tools to make `.inc` files from C headers with just the constants, also useful for getting stuff like `O_RDWR` or `MAP_PRIVATE` constants for syscall args.)

---

**If you're using any libc functions, especially `printf`, you should `call exit` to flush stdio buffers.**   Or `ret` from `main`, not `_start`, and let the CRT startup code call `exit`.  See also

- *[On x64 Linux, what is the difference between syscall, int 0x80 and ret to exit a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67676658/on-x64-linux-what-is-the-difference-between-syscall-int-0x80-and-ret-to-exit-a)*
- *[Syscall implementation of exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit)* - on modern GNU/Linux, `call _exit()` uses an `exit_group` system call.  Only `pthread_exit` actually uses `__NR_exit`.

---

As [@fuz explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674026/what-happens-if-there-is-no-exit-system-call-in-an-assembly-program/49674135#49674135), execution will continue into whatever bytes come next in memory where your executable is loaded / mapped.  The CPU doesn't know where your source ended, it just fetches and decodes bytes from memory.

Often there are some zero bytes of padding at the end of the `.text` section.  On 32-bit x86, `00 00` decodes as `add [eax], al`, a memory-destination add. It's `add [rax], al` in 64-bit mode.  That will fault<sup>1</sup> if RAX doesn't point to a writeable page.

RISC-V specifically chose its opcodes so `00 00 00 00` (and `00 00` compressed instructions) would be invalid instructions that fault, definitely not a NOP, so regions of zero-padding can't work as NOP sleds for exploits which send execution nearby instead of exactly to the bytes they want to execute.  Some older RISCs *do* run all-zero bytes as a NOP or non-faulting ALU instruction, but AArch64 similarly avoids this problem with `0000xxxx` as `udf #imm16`, an illegal instruction.

If execution gets past whatever `00` or non-zero garbage bytes are in memory, eventually it'll come to an unmapped or non-executable page.  This will also lead to an invalid page fault, just like a data access for a bad pointer, so you also get SIGSEGV on Unix-like systems.

(Or on primitive CPUs without memory protection, the instruction pointer could wrap.  e.g. on 8086, code-fetch from CS:IP wraps IP without affecting CS, so execution implicitly loops over a 64KiB region if it's all straight-line code with no jumps.)

If you're curious, run under a debugger and look at disassembly of the faulting instruction, and the hexdump of its machine code in case you recognize it as ASCII data or `00` padding.  ([Don't put data in the path of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642600/segmentation-fault-when-using-db-define-byte-inside-a-function) either.)

---

### Footnote 1: hardware `#PF` exception -> software `SIGSEGV`

The x86 CPU exception is `#PF`, a page fault.  The CPU will run the kernel's page-fault handler, which checks whether the process *should* be allowed to access that virtual address.

If so, it can allocate a new page for copy-on-write or just zeroed, or find an existing page of file data in the pagecache for regions mapped to files.  Then set up the page-table entry to "wire" that page into the process's address-space to handle a "minor" or "soft" page fault.  Or do I/O to get the page from disk, waking up to wire the page when the I/O is done (major or hard page fault).

But in this case, we're talking about a page the process doesn't have mapped, so it's an *invalid* page fault.  The kernel's page-fault handler will deliver a `SIGSEGV` segmentation-fault signal if this is a Unix-like OS, or do something similar for other OSes like Windows.

The default action for `SIGSEGV` signal is killing your process, if it hasn't set up a handler for that signal.  Not that you should; unless you know why your process should be raising `SIGSEGV`, [usually that's unrecoverable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258418/why-is-a-segmentation-fault-not-recoverable/70270762#70270762).

Note that "segmentation fault" is unrelated to x86 segments like CS and DS, because modern OSes use paging for memory protection, not x86 segments.  32-bit or 64-bit process on x86 Linux runs with CS base=0 / limit = unlimited.  The name is historical.

Comment: Note that AArch64 too maps `0000xxxx` to the undefined instruction `udf #imm16`.