# NASM Assembly segmentation fault when checking if a number is prime

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, nasm, primes

I'm trying to check if the number that is in the eax register is prime. Unfortunately, I always get information that it is not, and also the error "Segmentation fault". I'm new to assembly and I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong

```
section .data
    msg_prime db "It is a prime number", 0ah
    msg_prime_len equ $ - msg_prime
    msg_not_prime db "Is not a prime number", 0ah
    msg_not_prime_len equ $ - msg_not_prime

section .bss
    is_prime resb 1    ;   flag, that checks if prime number
section .text

global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 7
    mov ecx, 2
loop:
    cmp ecx, eax  ;   if reached 7
    jae end_loop

    xor edx, edx
    div ecx ;   eax/ecx

    cmp edx, 0  ;   check the rest from division
    je not_prime    ;   if the remainder is 0, the number is not prime

    inc ecx ;   go to next number
    jmp loop

not_prime:
    mov [is_prime], byte 0   ;  set is_prime na 0 (not prime)
    jmp end_loop

end_loop:
    ;   if is_prime==0 then not prime
    ;   if is_prime==1 then is prime
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    cmp byte [is_prime], 0
    je .not_prime
    mov ecx, msg_prime
    mov edx, msg_prime_len
    syscall
    jmp .end

.not_prime:
    mov rsi, msg_not_prime
    mov rdx, msg_not_prime_len
    syscall

.end:
    ;end program
    mov eax, 1
    syscall
```

Comment: `div` overwrites `eax`. Also the number of the `exit` syscall is not `1`, it's `60` (this is the cause of the fault).

Comment: [Nasm segmentation fault on RET in \_start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19760002) shows how to make exit system calls properly, avoiding [What happens if there is no exit system call in an assembly program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49674026)