# Assembly program crashes with segfault after repetitive add instructions to rax

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, gdb, nasm

I'm writing a simple "Hello, world!" assembly program on an AWS 64 bit Ubuntu Linux machine, it keeps segfaulting out. Here is the hello_world.asm file:

```
section .data

txt db "Hello, World!", 0x0a" 

section .text 
global _start 

 _start:
; SYSCALL WRITE(1,txt,14) 
    mov rax, 4 
    mov rbx, 1 
    mov rcx, txt 
    mov rdx, 14 
    int 0x80 

; SYSCALL EXIT(exit_code)
    mov rax, 93 
    mov rbx, 0 
    int 0x80
```

Here is how I assembly and link the program:

```
nasm -g -f elf64 hello_world.asm && ld hello_world.o
```

Output from running `./a.out`, there is a quick pause before the segfault:

```
Hello, World!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I can't figure out how to dump the core, if you could help with that as well that'd be great but here is the output from disassembly with `gdb`:

```
gdb ./a.out
layout asm
run
0x401019 <_start+25>   int    $0x80
0x40101b <_start+27>    mov    $0x5d,%eax
0x401020 <_start+32>    mov    $0x0,%ebx
0x401025 <_start+37>    int    $0x80
0x401027 add    %al,(%rax)        
0x401029 add    %al,(%rax)
0x40102b add    %al,(%rax)
0x40102d add    %al,(%rax)
0x40102f add    %al,(%rax)
0x401031 add    %al,(%rax)
0x401033 add    %al,(%rax)
```

The program doesn't exit properly with the `exit` syscall `93` and I didn't write any of the `add` instructions to `rax`. I'm assuming these are what is causing the segfault, how do I get rid of them? How do I get the program to not segfault out? Thanks again.

Comment: What makes you think 93 is the exit syscall? Also 64 bit should not use `int $0x80` (32 bit shouldn't either, but that's a different matter). The `add`s are just zero bytes decoded as instructions.

Comment: Near duplicate of [What happens if there is no exit system call in an assembly program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49674026) , with [Nasm segmentation fault on RET in \_start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19760002) showing correct ways to make an `_exit` system call.

Comment: *there is a quick pause before the segfault:*  Probably your system is set up to pipe a core file into some logging tool.  The pause is while that stuff runs.  (`/etc/systemd/coredump.conf`).  I disabled that on my system, IIRC just by setting `ulimit -c 0`, because playing around with asm tends to lead to a lot of segfaults and I didn't want them cluttering my system logs.  Or the fraction of a second delay.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, where do i find the proper syscall numbers?

Comment: `/usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h` defines `_NR_EXIT` as 93` obviously I'm doing something wrong I switched the 93 to 0 and the program actually exited.

Comment: `/usr/include/asm-generic$ cat unistd.h | grep "#define __NR_exit"#define __NR_exit 93#define __NR_exit_group 94`