# x86 Assembly using Mingw toolchain on Windows

Tags: assembly, x86

I am interested of learning x86 Assembly. Unfortunately I am unable to explain to myself the following thing:

Assembling my source file

```
as -o cpuid.o .\cpuid.s
```

Linking my object file

```
ld -o cpuid.exe cpuid.o
```

Debugging my executable file

```
gdb .\cpuid.exe
```

I get `Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction. 0x00007ff610f11010 in ___CTOR_LIST__ ()`

But when I do the assembling and linking in one command

```
gcc -o cpuid cpuid.s
```

I get zero errors on gdb and everything works fine. Why? How do I make it work using separate commands?

This is the content of cpuid.s

```
.section .data
output:
    .ascii "The processor Vendor ID is 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'\n"

.section .text
.globl main
main:
    mov $0, %eax
    cpuid
```

Comment: `gcc` links libc and some CRT startup `.obj` files, including code that calls `main` and exits after it returns.  Without that, did `ld` warn about picking the top of the `.text` section as the process entry point?  I assume your `.s` file only defines a `main` not a `_start`, otherwise it would have a link error with `gcc` without `-nostdlib`.

Comment: Or to put it another way, bare `ld` is a valid way to link programs that are written for that, but not for programs written to be linked like a C program.  And vice versa; most programs written to work with bare `ld` won't link with `gcc`, due to duplicate symbol errors.  So what's in your `cpuid.s`?  (Or a [mcve] of it that reproduces this behaviour.)

Comment: Your `main` doesn't `ret` or make an exit system call, so it can only exit by having execution fall into some other function that ends up next after linking!  ([What happens if there is no exit system call in an assembly program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49674026)).  If you single-step in a debugger, you can find out what's actually happening. Also, it's a `main` not `_start` or `WinMain@16` or whatever Windows linkers look for as an entry point, so you should definitely be getting a warning from `ld` which you left out of the question; people with the same problem probably have it, too.